# Randomized response on each Cypress.io cy.route() call

Tags: javascript, cypress

Using Cypress.io for end to end testings, I am trying to mock an API endpoint in which I am will to get 0 with probability 0.5 and 1 with probability 0.5 for each call. However, all my calls gets the same response, I have added a `console.log` inside a function that I am passing to the response (`getRandomStatusAndScore`), however, I see that the `console.log` is called only once so I guess that's why all the calls returns the same results by this `cy.route()`. Hints & ideas?`

```
const getRandom = () => {
  console.log(Math.random());
  return Math.random() > 0.5
      ? { status: 1, score: Math.round(Math.random() * 100) }
      : { status: 0 };
  }
};
```

```
cy.route({
      method: 'GET',
      url: '/api/status/*',
      response: getRandom(),
    });
```

Comment: Here, you're assigning a static Object value to the `response` property, by calling `getRandom()` yourself. You can instead pass your function, to let Cypress call it every time: `response: getRandom`

Comment: @blex unfortunately it did not work, the console.log is printed only once, I guess the cy.route is called only once and has the same response for all calls

Comment: Why do you need to recreate the random behaviour in the tests? It would be easier to test with a known value or sequence of values.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I want to visualize the progress of this process, would it be possible to get different responses from the same route? it's the same as getting a random one as far as I know.

Comment: Please explain "visualize the progress". Also show more of the test - specifically what triggers the API calls. If the test issues, say, a click() for each call it may be possible to issue a new cy.route() before each click.

Comment: @eric99 I got your point, fantastic idea, the trigger is setInterval calls, so I can control the timing within a test :+1:

Comment: *"the trigger is setInterval calls, so I can control the timing within a test"* ... with [cy.tick()](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/tick.html#Examples).